# Retrieve matrix content from Entries form field in an Entry

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to retrieve matrix content from a an Entry field `chooseTemplateExample` which has a matrix block `component` with a Entry field `component`.

```
{% for template in entry.chooseTemplateExample %}
  <a href="{{ template.url }}" class="btn btn-primary">View {{ template.title }} example</a><br>

  {% for block in template.component %}

     //Trying to get the matrix content within this "template"
     {% for block in entry.chooseComponentForTemplate %}
      {% for component in block.component %}
        {{ title }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you loop through your matrix, you're missing the `s` on `components`. Should be:

```
{% for block in template.components %}
```

Each item in that loop will be one of the blocks in the matrix. So then you can call `{{ block.component }}` directly.

FYI, in your code, it looks like that `component` field in the matrix block is loopable as well? If you're trying to loop through an entries field, and then loop through a matrix field per entry, and then loop through another field per matrix block, expect some serious performance issues.

Full code reference:

```
{% for template in entry.chooseTemplateExample %}
  <a href="{{ template.url }}" class="btn btn-primary">View {{ template.title }} example</a><br>

  {% for block in template.components %}
    {% for component in block.component %} {!-- Is this field really loopable? --}
      {{ title }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben. I updated my question as I mistyped. I do have a matrix block called `component` with an Entry field `component`. I'm trying to get the title of this Entry field `component`.

Comment: I'm getting the following error "Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "component"."

Answer (score 1):

OK I finally figured it out. Thanks Ben.

```
{% for template in entry.chooseTemplateExample %}

  <a href="{{ template.url }}" class="btn btn-primary">View {{ template.title }} example</a><br>

  {% for block in template.chooseComponentForTemplate %}

     {% for component in block.component %}
            {{ component.title }}
     {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```